# VBA to generate one pdf report with multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export-to-pdf

I am trying to create a VBA code which will generate a pdf report where multiple ranges from a sheet will be printed onto one page.
In order to achieve this the ranges have to follow after each, hope that make sense....

So far this is the code I have been able to write

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPrintReport1_Click()

Sheet11.Range("G1:T5,A6:O34,P6:AC34").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Environ("Userprofile") & "\OneDrive\Documents\Excel Templates\Management Reports\SCL_Report1.pdf"

End Sub
```

The ranges are charts and tables and I need them to printed one range under the other as a portrait pdf when a command button is pressed.

Currently one pdf is created but each range is printed on a separate sheet

Hoping someone can help...

Comment: `Sheet11.Range("A1:AC34").ExportAsFixedFormat...` ? Does this work?

Comment: I guess you need to share the locations of the tables and of the charts as in their addresses. BTW, `A6:O34` has 15 columns while the outer ranges have only 14 which may cause some issues. Also, share the images in the same measure because the tables need to be aligned vertically, and so do the charts. The idea is to copy the data to a new worksheet, each range one below the other, and then export that worksheet.